# C++ AttachConsole include error

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, console

How can I include AttachConsole? I always get "was not declared in this scope" error.

I found this "To compile an application that uses this function, define _WIN32_WINNT as 0x0501 or later. For more information, see Using the Windows Headers." on Microsoft MSDN [website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502

int main() {
    AttachConsole(8336);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course you need to define `_WIN32_WINNT` to be >= 0x0501, but you need to do so **before** including the Windows headers, else it will have no effect whatsoever.

Do this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0502
#include <windows.h>

int main() {
    AttachConsole(8336);
}
```

Comment: oh f*ck :D Ive been trying for hours.. :D